# Fortran Preprocessor Directive Usage

Tags: inheritance, fortran, preprocessor

Alright, so I may be using something in a way it wasn't supposed to be, but here is my problem. I'm trying to make an array that can hold different types that extend a single parent type. To do that (via this post https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/280765) it is suggested that I do it as follows.

```
program main

implicit none

type shape
    integer :: x,y
end type shape

type shape_c
    class(shape), pointer :: s
end type shape_c

type, extends(shape) :: rectangle
    integer :: w,h
end type rectangle

type, extends(shape) :: circle
    integer :: r
end type

type(rectangle) :: r
type(circle) :: c
type(shape) :: s

class(shape_c), dimension(:), allocatable :: shapes

r = initRect()
c = initCircle()
s = initShape()

allocate(shapes(3))

shapes(1)%s => r
shapes(2)%s => c
shapes(3)%s => s

write(*,*) shapes(1)%s%x * shapes(2)%s%x * shapes(3)%s%x

end program main
```

At the end of that post someone suggests that I use fpp to avoid having to write '%s' after shapes every time.  So I attempted to use the below just below program main.

```
#define shapes(m) shapes(m)%s
```

This of course works great except in the case of 'allocate(shapes(3))' which breaks the code. I am at a loss for how to avoid that happening.

So, may question is, is there a better way to do the array of inherited variables, a way to avoid the breaking during the allocate statement, or another solution to this problem. Also, a decent guide to how to use fpp would be helpful. https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/510271 is what I am using currently which I'm sure is helpful if I had ever used preprocessors before, but is not that useful to someone who hasn't.

I'm using Intel Visual Fortran 2015 and VS2012.

Comment: Why don't you just define the macro after the allocate?

Comment: For multiple reasons. The first is that as far as I can tell the preprocessor much be defined must be defined before the declaration of variables. Another is that even if I could define it anywhere the actual code is much more complicated than the example so it isn't as clear cut as that. I could I suppose write #define after statements and the #undef before statements, but that sounds like much worse option.

Comment: Sorry, never mind on the not defining elsewhere. That was a typo on my part. The rest still stands though.

Answer (score 0):

Both `shapes(m)` and `shapes(m)%s` have a meaning a meaning in Fortran and so redefining all `shapes(m)` as `shapes(m)%s` clearly breaks the code. You should use a non-Fortran keyword when defining a macro or at least use a word that is not present elsewhere. For example,

```
#define SHAPES(m) shapes(m)%s
```

(it is common to use caps with preprocessor macros) or something shorter if you insist on saving keystrokes. That being said, using the preprocessor for shortening the code is perhaps not the best style and might hurt readability. I suggest using the capabilities of your text editor for easily inserting the relevant code bits.

Comment: Yeah I agree that fpp isn't an ideal way to go. I just realized if I (or another on my team) wrote "shapes(1)%s%x" which is correct, it would break the code as well. Just having that redundant amount of code (there would never be a time I actually wanted to call "shapes(1)" without meaning "shapes(1)%s") is really bothering me. It doesn't seem like much, but this array is (very) frequently accessed an has many variables and derived types under it, and it seems like this would further the clutter problem. If the preprocessor handled some form of regex, it would be very convenient.

Comment: Oh yeah. In making an example I didn't notice I was using a Fortran keyword. The real code doesn't use a keyword. That isn't what is causing the break though.

Comment: `SHAPES` and `shapes` is the same in Fortran, the case is insignificant. It is significant to to the preprocessor, but still it will look confusing to a reader.

Comment: True, but looking at the example I had assumed the code is small- or mixed-case only. If so, then I would always suspect `SHAPES` is a preprocessor keyword (perhaps it's just me). To further avoid confusion, one could also add some underscores to the keyword.

Comment: The problem is that it makes the line "allocate(shapes(m)%s)". There doesn't seem to be a way to make the preprocessor smart enough to only do it under certain circumstances. Or I would prefer a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do with inheritance.

Comment: The C preprocessor doesn't recognize regular expressions and so using the same word everywhere is not possible in that sense.